# How to dismiss any popover viewcontrollers when activated in iOS?

Tags: ios, popover, dismiss

I have some ViewControlls for settings, info etc.
Users can close the app settings ViewController open(I mean popover the ViewController).
When local notification is received I want the the app go to the root viewcontroller and dismiss any popovers.

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT*
this answer is only good if the VC you are trying to go back to does not need any special initialization, since this method creates a new instance of it. keep that in mind.

Try this method, it will remove anything in your stack of View Controllers and make a specific View Controller presented on screen:

```
func dismissAllAndNavigate(){


    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let window = appDelegate.window
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let rootController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "some identifier") as! UIViewController
    window?.rootViewController = rootController
```

}

Just make sure that the name of the storyboard is correct and the identifier of the view controller in that storyboard is defined.

Comment: Keep in mind that this method **creates a new instance** of the root view controller.

Comment: true, this really is only good when your vc doesn't have special initialization going on in it, meaning it is always the same (like a vc that is only good for navigation between different vc's)